# solving congruence class equation

Tags: congruences

Keeping $p = 7$  is the following true?

> If for any congruence class $[a]$ that is not $[0]$, there is a unique
>   class $[b]$ such that $[a] \cdot [b] = [1]$.

Would this be true? (assuming you keep $p = 7$)

Comment: Yes.  For any prime, $\mathbb Z/p \mathbb Z$ is a field.

Comment: would that be true for p = 8,9 or 10

Comment: and how would you prove it ?

Comment: Welcome to Math SE! Please include what are your thoughts on the problem and show the work you have done so far to solve it. When you have a minute, please take the [tour of the site](http://math.stackexchange.com/tour) 
and look at [how to format mathematics here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) on Math SE. furthermore, may I suggest 
that you bookmark this [very useful MathJax link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) 
for quick reference. Cheers!

Comment: $8$, $9$ and $10$ are not primes.  For $p = 8$ or $10$, there is no $b$ for $a = 2$, since everything in $[2]\cdot[b]$ would be divisible by $2$.  For $p = 9$, there is no $b$ for $a=3$, since everything in $[2] \cdot [b]$ would be divisible by $3$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can show that $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ is a field if and only if $p$ is a prime. This implies that every element has a multiplicative inverse in this group.

However, if $p$ is not a prime, you have a ring with zerodivisors (and hence are not fields): take $x \in \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ such that $x \mid n$, which is possible since $n$ is not prime (in particular $1 < x < n$. This implies that $n = dx$ for some integer $d$ and hence we have that $[x][d] = [n] = 0$, whereas $x \neq 0$ nor $d \neq 0$. Hence these elements can't have multiplicative inverses.

Answer (score 0):

If there are two classes $[a]$ and $[b]$ such that $[a]\cdot [c]=[b]\cdot [c]=1$ that is, $[a]$ and $[b]$ are the inverse of $c$.

Since $\Bbb Z_7^*$ is a group, we can use the cancellation property and prove that $[a] = [b]$.

Comment: Welcome to Math SE! When you have a minute, please take the [tour of the site](http://math.stackexchange.com/tour) 
and look at [how to format mathematics here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) on Math SE. furthermore, may I suggest 
that you bookmark this [very useful MathJax link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) 
for quick reference. Cheers!

Comment: "Obviously" is rather rude and not needed. What is obvious to you might not be obvious to others, and if it were obvious to the OP, they wouldn't have asked.